# Command to close terminal window

Tags: terminal, bash

When I want to close a window I type `exit` :

```
 mbp-thomas in ~
○ → exit
logout

[Opération terminée]
```

Then <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> to close the window.

Is there a way to do it with a little script like if I type `quit` it exit the session then close the window ?

Comment: Can you configure Terminal to close when the shell closes?

Comment: @glennjackman that's a damn good question ! I'll try it right now

Comment: @glennjackman post it as an answer, you'll win +25

Comment: While the question already has a great answer, a quick tip on the side: `CTRL-D` does the same as typing `exit` and hitting `ENTER`, but is much quicker. Also works when logging off a remote server in an SSH session.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Open Terminal.
2. Go to **Terminal** → **Preferences…**.

   [image: Image of the Terminal panel]
3. Select the **Settings** tab, then your profile, and choose the **Shell** tab.
4. Set **When the shell exits** to **Close if the shell exited cleanly**.

   [image: Close if the shell exited cleanly]

Answer (score -1):

You could also simply quit Terminal by using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

Comment: He did not ask how to quit terminal.  This is not answer to his question.

Comment: True, and while it is technically and semantically different, for all intents and purposes, that is what's happening, except if there are multiple instances open (or wants an app without window processes running).